# Unassigned shards после settings

Tags: elasticsearch, settings

Создаю индекс делаю close
 потом применяю настройки. После делаю индекс open и шарды становятся unassigned. Процессор в напряжении и так постоянно. Может я где то в настройках ошибся?

`{ "settings": { "analysis": { "char_filter": { "ru": { "type": "mapping", "mappings": [ "Ё=>Е", "ё=>е" ] } }, "filter:": { "russian_stop": { "type": "stop", "stopwords": [ "а", "без", "более", "бы", "был", "была", "были", "было", "быть", "в", "вам", "вас", "весь", "во", "вот", "все", "всего", "всех", "вы", "где", "да", "даже", "для", "до", "его", "ее", "если", "есть", "еще", "же", "за", "здесь", "и", "из", "или", "им", "их", "к", "как", "ко", "когда", "кто", "ли", "либо", "мне", "может", "мы", "на", "надо", "наш", "не", "него", "нее", "нет", "ни", "них", "но", "ну", "о", "об", "однако", "он", "она", "они", "оно", "от", "очень", "по", "под", "при", "с", "со", "так", "также", "такой", "там", "те", "тем", "то", "того", "тоже", "той", "только", "том", "ты", "у", "уже", "хотя", "чего", "чей", "чем", "что", "чтобы", "чье", "чья", "эта", "эти", "это", "я" ], "ignore_case": "true" }, "custom_stop": { "type": "stop", "stopwords": [ "n", "r" ] }, "custom_word_delimiter": { "type": "word_delimiter", "generate_word_parts": "false", "generate_number_parts": "true", "catenate_words": "true", "catenate_numbers": "false", "catenate_all": "true", "split_on_case_change": "false", "preserve_original": "true", "split_on_numerics": "false" } }, "analyzer": { "russian_analyzer": { "type": "custom", "char_filter": [ "html_strip", "ru" ], "tokenizer": "standard", "filter": [ "stop", "custom_stop", "russian_stop", "custom_word_delimiter", "lowercase", "russian_morphology", "english_morphology" ] } } } }}`

Когда пытаюсь сделать рероут шарда то говорит что не может найти фильтр "custom_stop" хотя в настройках прописан. 
Может синтаксис корявый?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**filter:**": - двоеточие после filter лишнее. Вот рабочие настройки:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/rustest' -d '{  
   "settings":{  
      "analysis":{  
         "char_filter":{  
            "ru":{  
               "type":"mapping",
               "mappings":[  
                  "Ё=>Е",
                  "ё=>е"
               ]
            }
         },
         "filter":{  
            "russian_stop":{  
               "type":"stop",
               "stopwords":[  
"а","без","более","бы","был","была","были","было","быть","в","вам","вас","весь","во","вот","все","всего","всех","вы","где","да","даже","для","до","его","ее","если","есть","еще","же","за","здесь","и","из","или","им","их","к","как","ко","когда","кто","ли","либо","мне","может","мы","на","надо","наш","не","него","нее","нет","ни","них","но","ну","о","об","однако","он","она","они","оно","от","очень","по","под","при","с","со","так","также","такой","там","те","тем","то","того","тоже","той","только","том","ты","у","уже","хотя","чего","чей","чем","что","чтобы","чье","чья","эта","эти","это", "я"
               ],
               "ignore_case":"true"
            },
            "custom_stop":{  
               "type":"stop",
               "stopwords":[  
                  "n",
                  "r"
               ]
            },
            "custom_word_delimiter":{  
               "type":"word_delimiter",
               "generate_word_parts":"false",
               "generate_number_parts":"true",
               "catenate_words":"true",
               "catenate_numbers":"false",
               "catenate_all":"true",
               "split_on_case_change":"false",
               "preserve_original":"true",
               "split_on_numerics":"false"
            }
         },
         "analyzer":{  
            "russian_analyzer":{  
               "type":"custom",
               "char_filter":[  
                  "html_strip",
                  "ru"
               ],
               "tokenizer":"standard",
               "filter":[  
                  "stop",
                  "custom_stop",
                  "russian_stop",
                  "custom_word_delimiter",
                  "lowercase",
                  "russian_morphology",
                  "english_morphology"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

Comment: Блин! Спасибо! Я 3 дня себе череп ломаю! Вот чувствовал что кому то надо просто посмотреть свежими глазами! Спасибо еще раз!